# Prestashop with php-fpm gives uncomplete header error

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm

I am trying to run prestashop with apache. I have enabled mpm_event module.[this is my virtual host configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTdX6.png)

When I go to website I got the error

[apache error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MflC2.png)

### virtual host conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerName prestashop.varnish.com
ServerAlias www.prestashop.varnish.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/prestashop
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/prestashop_access.log combined
ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/prestashop_error.log
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    #Action php5-fcgi /php7-fcgi
    #Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/prestashop -socket /var/run/php/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>

<Directory /var/www/prestashop>
    Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### error log

```
[Sat Oct 08 08:25:09.896291 2016] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7993:tid 140080677115648] (2)No such file or directory: [client 192.168.10.205:58254] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/var/www/prestashop/index.php": connect() failed
[Sat Oct 08 08:25:09.896360 2016] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7993:tid 140080677115648] [client 192.168.10.205:58254] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/prestashop/index.php"
[Sat Oct 08 08:25:09.909828 2016] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7993:tid 140080668722944] (2)No such file or directory: [client 192.168.10.205:58255] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/var/www/prestashop/index.php": connect() failed, referer:
[Sat Oct 08 08:25:09.909880 2016] [fastcgi:error] [pid 7993:tid 140080668722944] [client 192.168.10.205:58255] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/prestashop/index.php", referer:
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `FastCGIExternalServer` you must start that process yourself. The error suggests it is either not started or is not listening on the socket provided

But if you are going to do that and you are using Apache v2.4 anyway you should definitely move to using mod_proxy_fcgi and `php-fpm`

Some extra info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082036/difference-between-fastcgiexternalserver-and-fastcgiserver-in-apache-fastcgi-php.

EDIT: Link to a configuration guide for `mod_proxy_fcgi` and `php-fpm`: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

Comment: I am using php5-fpm and have disabled php5 "a2dismod php5"

Comment: I am trying to do with php5-fpm. Can you help me with configuration ?

Comment: Have added a link to my original reply